# Construction of $\exists x_i (\phi)$ in first order logic.

Tags: first-order-logic

How do we construct $\exists x_i(\phi)$ where $\phi$ a formula from first order language by using:

- The logical symbols $(,),\neg,\to,\forall$
- The variable symbols $x_i$

Comment: its supposed to be equivalent to $\neg\forall x_i(\neg\phi)$

Answer (score 0):

There exists an x such that phi holds $\equiv$ It is not the case that for all x, phi does not hold.

ie. $\exists x_i(\phi) = \neg(\forall x_i(\neg\phi))$

Comment: Yes; if your language has only $\forall$ in the symbols-set, the only way to have $\exists$ is to introduce it as an *abbreviation*.